# Columns don't align. Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm using Bootstrap and I'm wondering why the columns don't align properly. The second column goes below the first even if I resize its width and make it fit. I'm really wondering. But my elements are properly coded. I tried even using inline block but it overlaps each other. Here's the code for the HTML and CSS

CODE: (HTML)

```
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "banner">
                <div class = "bannerimg">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-md-2">
                <div class = "navigation">
                    <div class = "sidenav1">
                        <ul class = "list">
                            <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Track</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Program</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Vehicles</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Prices</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Photos</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Our Staff</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Comments</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Links</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-8">
                <div class = "mainContent">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CODE: (CSS)

```
.bannerimg
{
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    height: 125px;
    max-width: 100%;    
    display: block;
}

.list
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.sidenav1
{
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    max-height: 40%;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.mainContent
{
    border-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 70%;

}
```

Comment: What size is your device you are testing on?  bootstrap is designed to be responsive and wrap columns when there's not enough room.   Perhaps using `sm` instead of `md` is what you want?

Comment: Issue in Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/J338LOBxGz. Use `sm` instead of medium if you want it next to it in small sizes. Is there a reason why your grid is not 8 and 4 or 10 and 2?

Comment: I'm using a laptop that's why I use md.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set widths to the columns, Bootstrap's `col-*` classes already set the appropriate widths in percentages, depending on the width of the viewport.

Try removing the `width`s from your CSS and then using `col-sm-4` on the sidebar and `col-sm-8` on the content, and see if that is the effect you wanted.

Check out the code snippet below (run it fullpage and resize your browser to see the layout changes).

```css
.bannerimg
{
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    height: 125px;
    max-width: 100%;    
    display: block;
}

.list
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.sidenav1 
{
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    max-height: 40%;
    /*width: 150px;*/
    margin-top: 20px;
}
    
.mainContent {
    border-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    margin-top: 20px;
    /*width: 70%;*/ 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "banner">
            <div class = "bannerimg">
                Some image
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-sm-4">
            <div class = "navigation">
                <div class = "sidenav1">
                    <ul class = "list">
                        <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Track</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Program</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Vehicles</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Prices</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Photos</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Our Staff</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Comments</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Links</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-8">
            <div class = "mainContent">
                Some content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is it that's not working? Maybe some other styles are colliding, I just used what you posted. How exactly do you need the columns to align?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to the sidenav style:

```
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0px;
```

That'll force it to push it right.

It's not completely at the top, because you have a top margin.

Here's a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/briggs_w/qvwp9wjg/

This is an answer that doesn't use Bootstrap features.  Not sure if that's what you want.